# why don't the colorzilla gradients work in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-9, gradient

I've been using the colorzila tool to generate some css gradients. They work in all browsers I test in save for IE9; haven't tried the other IE's yet.
They have an IE checkbox on their UI. When I set it to on, the gradient sample no longer has a gradient; it defaults to the base solid color.

I thought it should work in IE since they do include the following css function

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#221f1f', endColorstr='#221f1f',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

[http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#_](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a button under the css called

**IE9 Support (?)**

Make sure you check that *and* follow the instructions that appear.

Comment: did they just add that then? must be pretty recent. i'm following the instructiosn but it's still not working in IE9... apparently i should set the filter property to none. doing that with the dev toolbar gives me a blank background. it's setting a background-image property to some url; some svg image but it seems to be empty.

Comment: @towpse try it in the code itself rather than the dev toolbar.  See if that works?

Comment: So you need to put the code for the svg image in quotes; something the colorzilla tool isn't doing right now. e.g. background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,<binary-image-block>=")

Answer (score 3):

I suggest dropping those horrible `filter` styles. There is a much easier and more compatible solution available. [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) is a library that allows IE to make use of the standard CSS gradient syntax.

It's much easier to use than the `filter`, and easier to maintain in your code as well. It works in all versions of IE, and plus it also does the same trick for a few other CSS features too such as `border-radius`.

In addition, I would point out that the comment in your code snippet is incorrect -- your snippet says "IE6-9", but in fact the `filter` style has been discontinued in IE9, in favour of standard CSS syntax.

Unfortunately, this is a problem for you as IE9 doesn't support standard CSS gradients either. They've taken away something that worked (kinda) and replaced it with... nothing (in this case).

Fortunately, CSS3Pie does allow gradients, even in IE9, so it is the solution to your problem.

Hope that helps.